# Unable to replace &nbsp; in my android app

Tags: android, json

android version:4.2
my sample code is:

```
   try {
   //HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);

   text=text.replaceAll("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">").replace("&nbsp;", " ");

   int start=text.indexOf("<message>");
   start=start+9;
   int end=text.indexOf("</message>");
   text=text.substring(start, end);



   JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(text) ;
       // ITERATE THROUGH AND RETRIEVE CLUB FIELDS
    int n = ja.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        // GET INDIVIDUAL JSON OBJECT FROM JSON ARRAY
     JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

     title+= jo.getString("Title")+",";
     url= jo.getString("URL");
     desc= jo.getString("Description");                             
    }
 } catch (Exception e) {
         return e.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

issue: Varible desc(i.e., description in my json)contains `**&nbsp;**` in its contents.I have converted HTML into string in android using following code:

```
Spanned marked_up = Html.fromHtml(results);
tv2.setText(marked_up.toString(),BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Still it is not replacing `**&nbsp;**`.
Help me anyone plz.
ThankYou in advance.

Comment: thats a space that should be preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
marked_up.toString().replaceAll("&nbsp","");
```

Comment: @AfeejaShaik : what about my answer. have u try it?

Comment: @AfeejaShaik : but it's working perfectly   for me . anyway Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Use `tv2.setText(marked_up)` instead of `tv2.setText(marked_up.toString(),BufferType.SPANNABLE);`

Comment: Spanned sp =jo.getString("Description"); tv2.setText(sp) will this also work?

Comment: No, `JSONObject.getString` returns `String`, not `Spanned`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String unescapeHTML(String s, int f){
        String [][] escape = {{  "&nbsp;"   , " " }};
        int i, j, k;

        i = s.indexOf("&", f);
        if (i > -1) {
            j = s.indexOf(";" ,i);
            f = i + 1;
                if (j > i) {
                  String temp = s.substring(i , j + 1);
                  k = 0;
                  while (k < escape.length) {
                    if (escape[k][0].equals(temp)) break;
                    else k++;
                  }
                  if (k < escape.length) {
                    s = s.substring(0 , i) + escape[k][1] + s.substring(j + 1);
                    return unescapeHTML(s, f); 
                  }
               }
         }   
         return s;
    }
```

Use this function as `text = unescapeHTML(text,0);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this method,

```
Html.fromHtml(text);
title+= Html.fromHtml(jo.getString("Title"))+",";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change following line `desc= jo.getString("Description");` into this:

```
desc= Html.fromHtml(jo.getString("Description"));
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you should have to remove **&nbsp,<,>** from server side because you have to check different node every time.... so change on server side code of webservice... it will be best for you...

Comment: Why cant he do a client side thing ?